# Set a view with SlidingPaneLayout with two menu's- one to the left and one to the right

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingpanelayout

i'm trying to create a SlidingPaneLayout that can slide both ways, same as they have in the Facebook app.
i see in android SlidingPaneLayout docs, that it is only intended to have a left menu, but still i'm looking for a way to make the child view slide both ways.

any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try this library: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu